# SQL aggregate and other fields showing in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

I have a query, where I need the `MIN` of a DateTime field and then I need the value of a corresponding field in the same row.

Now, I have something like this, however I cannot get `Price` field without putting it also in an aggregate clause, which is not what I want.

`SELECT MIN([Registration Time]), Price FROM MyData WHERE [Product Series] = 'XXXXX'`

I need the `MIN` of the `Registration Time` field and then I just want the corresponding `Price` field for that row, however how do I show that?

I do also need my `WHERE` clause as shown.

I'm sure I've overlooked something really obvious. Using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want just one record with `[Registration Time], Price`, it'd be as simple as this:

```
select top 1 [Registration Time], Price
from MyData
where [Product Series] = 'XXXXX'
order by [Registration Time]
```

If you want minimum `[Registration Time]` and corresponding `Price` for all `[Product Series]`, then there's a few approaches, for example, using row_number() function:

```
with cte as (
    select
        [Registration Time], Price,
        row_number() over(partition by [Product Series] order by [Registration Time]) as rn
    from MyData
)
select
    [Registration Time], Price, [Product Series]
where rn = 1
```